# Jquery UI Slider Increment and decrement

Tags: jquery, user-interface, uislider

[image]

**I have a slider which has 4 handler, each handler has their own popup with decrements and increments,
how can i move the sliders while clicking on minus(-) and plus(+) button.**

Please help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

according to [documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/#option-value)

You can set the value like

```
$( ".selector" ).slider( "option", "value", 10 );
```

or

```
var slider = $( "#slider" ).slider();

slider.slider('value',10);
```

Use your logic to increment or decrement the value

**UPDATE**

Check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Cerlin/qkwjoLcz/15/) updated fiddle

I have changed the logic a little bit

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var i = parseInt(160);  
    var values = [140, 160, 180, 200];
    var vitalslider = slider(values);

    $('#increment').on('click', function(){
        i++;
        values[1] = i;
        vitalslider.limitslider('destroy');
        vitalslider = slider(values);
    });
    $('#decrement').on('click', function(){
        i--;
        values[1] = i;
        vitalslider.limitslider('destroy');
        vitalslider = slider(values);
    });

    function slider(values){
        return  $('#basic').limitslider({
                    values: values,
                    value:'',
                    min: 140,
                    max: 200,
                    limitCls:'vital_limit',
                    showRanges: true,
                    left: 100,
                    label: true,
                    ranges: [false, true, true, true]
                });
    }
});
```

Comment: `var slider = $('#basic').limitslider();
slider.limitslider("option", "value", 10);
`
i have 4 handlers so i used values too.
`slider.limitslider("option", "values", handlerindex, 10);`
** 
it moves the black circle but not slider.
**

Comment: create a jsfiddle reproducing the problem and share it.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. In this QA site, when an answer is realized, we do not append "(SOLVED)" to the question title. Instead, we mark a correct answer by clicking on the checkbox to the upper-left of that answer. If you come up with the answer yourself, then post your own answer, give it some time, and if no one has a better answer (your discretion), you can accept your own after a 48-hour wait period.

Comment: Hi Cerlin,

What about the first handler and last handler, it doesn't move...
left or right. Can you please help me out.

Comment: `values` is an array indexing from 0 to 3. so if you update that it will work